# How to rebind keys to key combinations?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

I really would like to switch to Linux, but there is still this one last thing I just can't get working. On Windows I'm using **autohotkey** to rebind some keys to key combinations, and I'm just too used to it to use the system without it.

I'm using the following bindings:

```
LAlt + j = LeftArrow
LAlt + k = Enter
LAlt + l = RightArrow
LAlt + i = UpArrow
LAlt + , = DownArrow

LAlt + Shift + j = Ctrl + LeftArrow
LAlt + Shift + k = Shift + Enter
LAlt + Shift + l = Ctrl + RightArrow

LAlt + p = Backspace
LAlt + [ = Delete
LAlt + Shift + p = Ctrl + Backspace
LAlt + Shift + [ = Ctrl + Delete

LAlt + c = copy
LAlt + x = cut
LAlt + v = paste
```

I have tried using the Linux equivalent of autohotkey - **Autokey**, but it's too high level to be usable, even in Firefox up and down arrows won't work like they should.

I have also tried **xmodmap**, but it seems to be impossible to achieve my bindings with it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: It's just the default Ubuntu 20.04 installation with gnome